# Bootstrap expand menu / navbar by percentage, and scrollable if needed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have asked similar to this earlier, but trying to clarify better as I didn't have any replies on my last one ;) Thanks!

---

I have a navbar/menu expanding in Bootstrap in the view 'xs' view (hamburger button).

- How do I get the navbar/meny to expand to 100% and become scrollable if needed?

Original code:

```
#menu1 .navbar-collapse{padding:0;}
```

When using the original code the menu opens to roughly 50 percent of the screen area, and the dropdown menu becomes scrollable (which is good).

My code (me trying to find the solution):

```
#menu1 .navbar-collapse{padding:0; min-height:100%}
```

When I try my addition the css above, nothing happens. Still looks the same. How come the min-height: 100% does not expand the drop down all the way?

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you very much.
/Marcus

---

CSS of the entire menu:

```
/* menu 1 - XS view */
#menu1 { background-color: #f5f5f5; min-height: 40px;}
#menu1 .navbar-collapse{padding:0; min-height: 100%;}
#menu1 .nav > li > a { color: #000; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; min-height: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-size:14px;}
#menu1 .nav > li:hover > a, #menu1 .nav > li.open > a { background-color:#008080; color:#fff; border-radius:3px;}
#menu1 .dropdown-menu { padding-bottom: 0; }
#menu1 .dropdown-inner { display: table; }
#menu1 .dropdown-inner ul { display: table-cell; }
#menu1 .dropdown-inner a { min-width: 175px; display: block; padding:4px 20px; clear: both; line-height: 20px; color: #333333; font-size: 12px; }
#menu1 .dropdown-inner li a:hover { color: #008080; }
#menu1 .see-all { display: block; margin-top: 0.5em; border-top: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 3px 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; }
#menu1 .see-all:hover, #menu .see-all:focus { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; background-color: #008080;}
#menu1 #category { float: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 40px; color: #000; margin-left:15px;}
#menu1 .btn-navbar {font-size: 15px; font-stretch: expanded; color: #FFF; padding: 2px 18px; float: right; background-color: #008080;}
#menu1 .btn-navbar:hover, #menu1 .btn-navbar:focus, #menu1 .btn-navbar:active, #menu1 .btn-navbar.disabled, #menu1 .btn-navbar[disabled] { color: #ffffff; background-color: #000; }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #menu1 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#menu1 .navbar-nav{margin:0;}
#menu1 .in{border-top:1px dotted #bbb;}
#menu1 {
 border-radius: 4px;
}
 #menu1 div.dropdown-inner > ul.list-unstyled {
 display: block;
}
 #menu1 div.dropdown-menu {
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-color:#fff;
}
 #menu1 .dropdown-inner {
 display: block;
}
 #menu1 .dropdown-inner a {
 width: 100%;
 color: #222;
}
 #menu1 .dropdown-menu a:hover, #menu .dropdown-menu ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#eee;
}
 #menu1 .see-all {
 margin-top: 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #222;
}
#menu1 .see-all:hover{color: #008080;}
}
```

HTML:

```
  <nav id="menu1" class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs"><?php echo str_replace("Categories","Menu",$text_category);; ?></span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><b><?php echo $text_home;  ?></b></a></li>

            <li><a href="/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4"><b>About us</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=6"><b>Find us</b></a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8"><b>Buy or sell</b></a></li>  -->
            <li><a href="/index.php?route=information/contact"><b>Contact us</b></a></li>

    </uL>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">



        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> 

            <div class="dropdown-inner">
              <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It works using **'vh'** instead of 'px'.  The height of the viewport:

```
#menu1 .navbar-collapse{ padding:0; min-height: 70vh;}
```